# VisualStateManager not working when value is passed through a converter for applying a Button Bg

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am applying a button's background color through a converter. At first it is applied properly but after it is hovered or pressed the background color is gone forever and does not come back.

**Desired Behavior**

Default State

[image: noraml]

Hovered

[image]

After Hover State

[image: noraml]

**My Problem**

The orange background does not appear again when the hovered state is over

**IMPLEMENTATION**

Button Usage

```
<Button Content="Continue" Style="{StaticResource ButtonAnyColorStyle}">
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding something, Converter={StaticResource PanelBgColorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Button Style

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonAnyColorStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=ButtonBackground}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=ContentContainer}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=ButtonBackground}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=ButtonBackground}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=ContentContainer}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=ButtonBackground}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                              Value="0.2" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="12"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Converter

```
 public class PanelBgColorConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is something)
        {
            switch ((something)value)
            {
                case something.AppTheme:
                    return Application.Current.Resources["AppThemeColorOnly"];

                case something.Phone:
                    return Application.Current.Resources["AppGreenColorOnly"];

                case something.Email:
                    return Application.Current.Resources["AppYellowColorOnly"];

                default:
                    return Colors.Transparent;
            }
        }
        else return Colors.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please note that if a color is passed as StaticResource via XAML, the behavior is perfect. The problem lies with converted value